# Join a table whose name is stored in the first table

Tags: sql-server

I have a first table `[TABLE1]` with columns `[ID]`, `[Description]`, `[DetailTable]`. I want to join `[TABLE1]` with the `[DetailTable]`. The name of `[DetailTable]` is stored in `[TABLE1]` column.

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE1 CROSS JOIN ?????"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible design. As stated previously you will have to use dynamic sql for this. Nobody can give you an example because there isn't enough information in your question. Instead of trying to figure out the dynamic sql route I would urge you to fix your database design.

Comment: If the number of possible tables is small ( 2 or 3?) You could join into all of them and then filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

So... if you cheat and `SELECT *` from the detailtab, you could do something a bit like this, with dynamic SQL:

```
-- For the example, choose either 1 or 2 to see the #foo table or the #bar table
DECLARE @Id INT = 1

-- EXAMPLE SCENARIO SETUP --
CREATE TABLE #ListOfTables
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL 
 ,[Description] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
 ,[DetailTable] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE #foo
(Foothing VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE #bar
(Barthing VARCHAR(20));

-- TEST VALUES --
INSERT #ListOfTables VALUES ('foo','#foo'),('bar','#bar');
INSERT #foo VALUES ('A foothing Foothing');
INSERT #bar VALUES ('A barthing Barthing');


-- THE SCRIPT -- 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @SQL =
'   SELECT Tab.Id, Tab.[Description], Tab2.*
    FROM #ListOfTables AS Tab
    CROSS JOIN ' + T.DetailTable + ' AS Tab2
    WHERE Tab.Id = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Id)
FROM #ListOfTables T
WHERE T.Id = @Id;

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

-- CLEAN UP --
DROP TABLE #ListOfTables;
DROP TABLE #bar;
DROP TABLE #foo;
```

However, I have to agree with the comments that this is a pretty nasty way to do things. If you want to choose particular columns and the columns are different for each detail table, then things will start to get really unpleasant... Does this give you something you can start with?

Remember, the best solution will almost certainly involve redesigning things so you don't have to jump through these hoops!

Answer (score 0):

All of the detail tables must have identical schema.

Create a view that unions all the tables

```
CREATE VIEW vAllDetails AS
SELECT 'DETAIL1' table_name, * from DETAIL1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DETAIL2' table_name, * from DETAIL2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DETAIL3' table_name, * from DETAIL3
```

When you join against this view, SQL Server can generate a plan that uses a "startup predicate expression".  For example, a plan like this: [sample plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByC9ZRLBq).  At first glance, it looks like SQL is going to scan all of the detail tables, but it won't.  The left most filters include a "startup predicate", so for each row we read from table1, only if TableName matches will that branch be executed.